# Lodash - Determine if array of object includes a value specified in a 2-dimensional array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array of required field names where the presence of either/any would count as valid. I am representing this in a 2-dimensional array as such:

```
const REQUIRED_FIELDS = [
  ['amount', 'presets'],
  ['payment_types', 'credit_card']
]
```

I am comparing this against an array of objects that that look as such:

```
const FIELDS = [
  {
    type: 'name',
    label: 'Your Name'
  },
  {
    type: 'credit_card',
    label: 'Credit Card'
  }
]
```

### Invalid Example

```
const FIELDS = [
  {
    type: 'name',
    label: 'Your Name'
  },
  {
    type: 'credit_card',
    label: 'Credit Card'
  }
]
```

This would be invalid as we have one from the second set (credit_card) but not the first (amount, presets)

### Valid Example

```
const FIELDS = [
  {
    type: 'name',
    label: 'Your Name'
  },
  {
    type: 'credit_card',
    label: 'Credit Card'
  },
  {
    type: 'amount',
    label: 'Amount'
  }
]
```

We have one from each here.

### Desired Result

- Either an array of booleans, like:

  `[[true, false], [true, false]]`
- Or an array of the missing required fields, like:

  `[['amount', 'presets'], []]`

I think I can get this done with Lodash's [some](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#some) and [includes](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#includes), but I'm having a major brain fart. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

#### Solution

Here's what ended up working for me. I'm sure this could be more optimized.

```
function validity(fields) {
  const validityMap = REQUIRED_FIELDS.map(arr =>
    fields.map(obj => {
      return obj.type, arr.indexOf(obj.type) > -1
    })
  )
  return validityMap.map(y => y.indexOf(true) > -1)
}
```

Thanks to Mr Greek for getting me there.

Comment: So a valid example would be composed of three objects, one for name, one for amount or preset and one for credit card or payment types?

Comment: No, 'name' is not required. I put it in there for dummy data. Sorry if that was confusing.

Comment: so what if none of the required fields is present for a input set? the same `require_field` will be the output right? with respect to your second example of output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you simply `filter` the require fields (with reference to your 2nd output type)

```
REQUIRED_FIELDS.filter(function(el){
    return !FIELDS.some(function(o){
        return el.indexOf(o.type)>-1;
    })
})
```

```js
const REQUIRED_FIELDS = [
  ['amount', 'presets'],
  ['payment_types', 'credit_card']
];
const FIELDS_1 = [
  {
    type: 'credit_card',
    label: 'Credit Card'
  }
];
const FIELDS_2 = [
  {
    type: 'credit_card',
    label: 'Credit Card'
  },
  {
    type: 'amount',
    label: 'Amount'
  }
];
const FIELDS_3 = [
  {
    type: 'presets',
    label: 'Presets'
  }
];

function getValidity(fields) {
    return REQUIRED_FIELDS.filter(function(el) {
      return !fields.some(function(o) {
        return el.indexOf(o.type)>-1;
      });
    });
}

console.log(getValidity(FIELDS_1));
console.log(getValidity(FIELDS_2));
console.log(getValidity(FIELDS_3));
```

And if you want a empty array for the required fields that are present, then just change the `.filter` with a `.map` simply and change the return value as expected in map instead of filter

```js
const REQUIRED_FIELDS = [
  ['amount', 'presets'],
  ['payment_types', 'credit_card']
];
const FIELDS_1 = [
  {
    type: 'credit_card',
    label: 'Credit Card'
  }
];
const FIELDS_2 = [
  {
    type: 'credit_card',
    label: 'Credit Card'
  },
  {
    type: 'amount',
    label: 'Amount'
  }
];
const FIELDS_3 = [
  {
    type: 'presets',
    label: 'Presets'
  }
];

function getValidity(fields) {
    return REQUIRED_FIELDS.map(function(el) {
      return fields.some(function(o) {
        return el.indexOf(o.type)>-1;
      }) ? [] : el;
    });
}

console.log(getValidity(FIELDS_1));
console.log(getValidity(FIELDS_2));
console.log(getValidity(FIELDS_3));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()`:

```js
const REQUIRED_FIELDS = [
  ['amount', 'presets'],
  ['payment_types', 'credit_card']
];
const FIELDS_1 = [
  {
    type: 'credit_card',
    label: 'Credit Card'
  }
];
const FIELDS_2 = [
  {
    type: 'credit_card',
    label: 'Credit Card'
  },
  {
    type: 'amount',
    label: 'Amount'
  }
];
const FIELDS_3 = [
  {
    type: 'presets',
    label: 'Presets'
  }
];
function validity(fields) {
  return fields.map((obj) =>
    REQUIRED_FIELDS.map((arr) =>
      arr.indexOf(obj.type)>-1
    )
  );
}
console.log(validity(FIELDS_1));
console.log(validity(FIELDS_2));
console.log(validity(FIELDS_3));
```

Comment: This almost works... I wanted to map it against the REQUIRED_FIELDS, not the fields itself. With this method I am getting a potentially huge validity map depending on how many fields there are. I'll try my hand at reversing

Comment: Updated my questions with the solution I used. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad I helped :).